# day() vs dayofmonth() in mysql

Tags: mysql

Consider

```
select day("2016-05-22")
```

and

```
select dayofmonth("2016-05-22")
```

both gives the same output.

```
day("2016-05-22")
22
```

and

```
dayofmonth("2016-05-22")
22
```

Is there any diffrence between these two methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) `DAY()` is a synonym for `DAYOFMONTH()`